# How does type ahead in ElasticSearch work on multiple words and partial text match

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I would like to explain with an example. 
Documents of my ElasticSearch dataset has a field 'product_name'. 
One document has product_name = 'Anmol Twinz Biscuit"
When the user types (a)'Anmol Twin' or (b)'Twin Anmol' or (c)'Twinz Anmol' or (d) Anmol Twinz, I want this specific record returned as search result. 
However, this works only if I specify the complete words in the search query. Partial matches are not working. Thus (a) & (b) is not returning the desired result.

Mapping defined (obtained by _mapping query)

```
{
    "sbis_product_idx": {
        "mappings": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "category_name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "product_company": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "product_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "product_name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "product_price": {
                        "type": "float"
                    },
                    "suggest": {
                        "type": "completion",
                        "analyzer": "simple",
                        "preserve_separators": true,
                        "preserve_position_increments": true,
                        "max_input_length": 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query being used:

```
{
  "_source": "product_name",    
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
       "type":   "best_fields",
      "query":    "Twin Anmol", 
      "fields": [ "product_name", "product_company" ],
      "operator":   "and"
    }
  }
}
```

The document in ES

```
{
  "_index": "sbis_product_idx",
  "_type": "misc",
  "_id": "107996",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "suggest": {
      "input": [
        "Anmol",
        "Twinz",
        "Biscuit"
      ]
    },
    "category_name": "Other Product",
    "product_company": "Anmol",
    "product_price": 30,
    "product_name": "Anmol Twinz Biscuit",
    "product_id": 107996
  }
}
```

Result

```
"hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
}
```

Mistake in query / mapping?

Comment: Can you provide the complete mapping of your index, so that its easy to test locally

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal I have updated the mapping in the original post. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I just created the index with your mapping and indexed ES doc given in your example and just changed the **operator** in your query from `and` to `or` and it's giving me all result for all 4 query combinations.

Find below my query

```
{
  "_source": "product_name",    
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
       "type":   "best_fields",
      "query":    "Anmol Twinz", 
      "fields": [ "product_name", "product_company" ],
      "operator":   "or" --> changed it to `or`
    }
  }
}
```

**With `and` operator your query tries to find both terms in your search query, some of which are not complete token like `Twin` in ES, hence you were not getting results for them, when you change your operator to `or` then if any of the token present, it will match.**

Note:- if you want to match on partial tokens like `Twin` or `Twi` then, you need to use the n-gram tokens as explained in official ES doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html  and its a completely different design.